# Generate file numbering sequence in while(1) loop

Tags: python, opencv, while-loop

I'm doing some background subtraction in python's openCV and want to have a useful output to work with. The tutorial [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/db/d5c/tutorial_py_bg_subtraction.html) includes code for several methods for background subtraction but running each in Rodeo leads to a separate window opening, and an image flashing before disappearing only to be replaced by the next frame.

I want to store each frame as its own image so that I can work with each further down a processing stream. However, trying to add an imwrite command is hindered because I can't name each file independently (as I could using a `for` loop, for example with `cv.imwrite('bg'+str(i)+'.jpg', fgmask)`).

Ultimately, `cv.imshow()` in the example code below is useful for visualization but I want to save each image with a unique, sequential filename. So, rather than `cv.imshow()` I'd like to use a `cv.imwrite()` line that writes each frame with a sequential file numbering system.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
cap = cv.VideoCapture('vtest.avi')
fgbg = cv.bgsegm.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG()
while(1):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    fgmask = fgbg.apply(frame)
    cv.imshow('frame',fgmask)
    k = cv.waitKey(30) & 0xff
    if k == 27:
        break
cap.release()
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define i = 0 before your while loop and increase it in your loop and use it for your file name.